# Cannnot send request to the users/signup route and failing to make connection to the database

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Below is the sign up controller...

```
const signup = async (req, res) => {
  const { name, username, profilePhoto, email, password } = req.body;
  console.log(req.body);
  try {
    const existingUser = await User.findOne({ email });
    if (existingUser)
      return res.status(404).json({ message: "User already exist." });

    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 12);
    const result = await User.create({
      name,
      username,
      email,
      profilePhoto,
      password: hashedPassword,
    });
    const token = jwt.sign(
      {
        name: result.name,
        email: result.email,
        username: result.username,
        id: result._id,
      },
      "test",
      {
        expiresIn: "1h",
      }
    );
    res.status(200).json({ result: result, token });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Something went wrong" });
  }
};
```

This is the code for action for SignUp

```
export const signup = (formData, history) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    // sign up the user
    const { data } = await api.signUp(formData);
    dispatch({ type: "AUTH", data });
    toast.success("Signed Up successfully");
    history.push("/feedbacks");
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({ type: "ERROR", data: error?.response?.data });
    toast.error(error?.response?.data?.message);
  }
```

While signing in I am getting proper response on the console in the backend. But unable to SignUp.
Error:
[image]

But the output of console has the response:
[image]

Other functionalities are also working in sync with Front-End

routes

[image]

Index.js

```
const express = require("express");
const connectDB = require("./config/db");
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();

const feedbacksRoutes = require("./routes/feedbacks");
const userRoutes = require("./routes/users");

app.use(express.json({ extended: false }));
app.use(cors());

// connect to mongoDB
connectDB();

app.use("/feedbacks", feedbacksRoutes);
app.use("/user", userRoutes);
```

Comment: Can you post the code where you are defining the route? Is the route defined as POST?

Comment: @FirminoChangani Yes, I used it as post

Comment: can you post the global route definition? The place where you imported `users.js`.

Comment: Seems right. Is it possible that the function connectDB() is hanging, thus `app.use(...)` is never set? Try to move them just above connectDB().

Comment: It sounds like there is a problem with `connectDB()` then that you will need to figure out.